# Can authentication be skipped for specific xquery endpoint in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

I am facing a problem like http call from java to xquery endpoint is slow some time and quick after that slow call, if i again leave it idle and try it is slow again. I assume digest authentication might be the problem.

Comment: Are you using the marklogic java api? As far as I know it uses OkHttp as http library. Might be because of connection pooling.

Comment: I use apache httpclient to hit xquery endpoint directly and not using marklogic java api's

Comment: Is the connection to the endpoint slow or is it the endpoint which executes a slow code ? Might be that data which your endpoints uses is cached and evicted after some time. Can you show the code of your endpoint? Have your tried that behaviour with a simple/empty code endpoint ? I (like Mads Hansen) do not think that authentication is the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't assume that authentication is the issue, but if you would like to try connecting without having to authenticate, you can set authentication to application level and assign a user for your appserver.

[Application Level](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/authentication#id_60432)

> Application-level authentication bypasses all authentication and automatically logs all users in as a specified default user. You specify the default user in the Admin Interface, and any users accessing the server automatically inherit the security attributes (roles, privileges, default permissions) of the default user. Application-level authentication is available on HTTP, ODBC, and WebDAV servers.

Scroll to the Authentication field. Select application-level and fill in a Default User. Any one accessing the HTTP server is automatically logged in as the Default User until the user logs in explicitly.

[image]

> If you use an admin user (admin) as the Default User (an authorized administrator with the admin role), then everyone who uses this App Server is automatically a user with the admin role, which effectively turns off security for this App Server.